# how can I remove additional points in below image quickly and improve quality of existing dash lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hi I want to improve the quality of this simple figure for my thesis. Can someone help me for removing additional points in this image and improve line and dashed-line Quality in this figure. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE. What have you tried, what didn't work? You can simply use levels to get rid of half-greys and refill the colored area — have you tried this?

Comment: Ideally, I'd redraw this in a vector app. It's merely shapes and paths.

Comment: Thanks. can you introduce a proper app for redrawing?

Comment: Vector applications: Adobe Illustrator, CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, Inkscape (free). Or if you want something simpler LibreOffice Draw, or maybe even just MS Word would do.